# WebSocket connection closes when server sends message only on port 80

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have a simple, local Nodejs server running Express. I'm using express-ws to set up a WebSocket endpoint. The client sends messages fine, and the server receives them, but when the server tries to send a message back, the connection closes and the client never receives the message.

This only happens over port 80. The connection stays open over port 3000, 8080, 443, and the client receives the messages the server sends back.

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  res.send(`<script src="js/client.js"></script>`);
});

app.ws('/', function(ws, req) {
  ws.on('message', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    ws.send(msg); //The connection doesn't close with this commented out
  });
});

app.listen(80);
```

client.js

```
const ws = new WebSocket(`ws://${window.location.host}`);

ws.onopen = function(e){
  console.log("WebSocket connected");
    ws.send("testing 1");
    ws.send("testing 2");
}

ws.onmessage = function(msg){
  console.log(msg);
}
```

I'm at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The above code is working just as expected when I tested it. Maybe expand on the example a little bit? Are you using websockets anywhere else in your app or some other middleware interfering with the requests?

Comment: Yeah, it works for me too. Try and see if this provides more info: `sudo env DEBUG=* node app.js`

Comment: I'm not using any middleware, but I tried this in a different environment on a different network and it works fine. So it's not the code. Thanks for your help.